# How can I run exe files in Dolphin on Kubuntu

Tags: kubuntu, wine, mime-type

I have wine installed. But how can I set it default for running exe files?

Comment: If wine is installed correctly, double click an executive file will open that file using wine by default. Please edit your question and provide more details, such as the version of Ubuntu, how did you install wine, what happens when you double click on an executive file?

Comment: Should your title say "How can I use Wine..." rather than "mime"?

Comment: @user68186 - In Kubuntu 18.04 I had the same problem with the stable wine version installed, had to create a desktop file as indicated in my answer  below.

Comment: @CentaurusA - I have simply edited the title to make things clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you right-click on the .exe file, you go to "Open with application with", then you select WINE.

Comment: In case `exe` files are not run as expected on (double) click (case implied by the OP, otherwise the question makes no sense), it might also be that no "Wine" program appears when trying to select it from "Open with".

Comment: For some reason, WINE is not an option. I have version 6.0, as this is the latest version I can get from the repos.

Answer (score 1):

Normally simply executing the exe file with (double) click in the file manager should run it through Wine. If for some reason that doesn't happen (beside trying to re-install Wine in order to get the expected behavior) you could do the following:

In terminal run `wine path_to_file.exe`.

---

In order to run it with (double) click: create a `~/.local/share/application/wine.desktop` file with the lines like

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=wine %f
Name=Run in Wine
Mimetype=application/x-dosexec
Categories=System;Settings;
```

then make *Run in Wine* the default "application" for exe files (in Dolphin: *Properties > (tab) General > Add*).

---

Alternatively, create a `~.local/share/kservices5/ServiceMenus/run_wine.desktop` like

```
[Desktop Entry]
Actions=wine
Mimetype=application/x-dosexec
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
Type=Service
X-KDE-Priority=TopLevel

[Desktop Action wine]
Exec=wine %f
Name=Run in Wine
Icon=wine
```

in order to have a right-click context menu option ("Service Menu") in Dolphin.

---

I cannot test now, as I don't use Wine as we speak, but `konsole -e wine %f` or `sh -c 'wine %f'` might be needed for the `Exec` line.

***If someone can confirm `Exec=wine %f` works, please comment.***

Comment: There are some typos here. `~.local` should be `~/.local`, and `application` should be `applications`.